# Is there a Stack Exchange site for Etiquette?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question I am trying to get answered about the proper etiquette for a situation I am dealing with. Is there a Stack Exchange site for that?

To be more specific, I am trying to figure out the proper etiquette for making contact with the owner of the (empty) land next door to me, for the purpose of purchasing the land from him.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of etiquette? There isn't a general one that I know of but Workplace deals with professionalism, which is "workplace etiquette"... Though there is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86480/etiquette).

Comment: @Catija: see edit. I guess you would call it "business transaction" etiquette.

Comment: you want advice on how to phrase the letter? That's likely to be opinion based and off-topic everywhere. There's [law](http://law.stackexchange.com/) of course but you should check its help centre carefully to make sure you'd be on topic there.

Comment: @RobertLongson: No - I'm looking for advice as to how to approach the situation. Specifically, I sent a letter three weeks ago and haven't gotten a response. I was trying NOT to ask the question here, though, as it doesn't seem appropriate for this board.

Comment: More likely you actually need to ask the advice of a real lawyer as far as I can tell.

Comment: You could go to you local council/Government website and seek advice from there - they'll likely have an appropriate department.

Comment: 1) set land on fire 2) watch who arrives to put out fire 3) offer to buy burnt land at cut rate prices

Answer (score 5):

[**Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) (IPS) might be your best bet.<sup>*</sup> We do take questions about [etiquette](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette), [courtesy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/courtesy) and [politeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness). We used to get more of these when the site was young (i.e. three months ago), and I think, judging by the moods of users, they're a bit less popular now, but they're certainly on-topic.

If and when you do ask your question on IPS, please do specify some things, including the details of the situation and the cultural setting. We try to avoid being overly broad, so we don't get dozens of answers about irrelevant situations that don't affect you.

Please note, though, that questions about Stack Exchange should be asked *here*, on Meta Stack Exchange, using the [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) tag. [Stack Exchange questions are off-topic on IPS](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1371/102); this includes questions about Stack Exchange etiquette.

---

<sup>*</sup> I'm a moderator on IPS.

Comment: To clarify, IPS accept questions about etiquette (and net-etiquette) however, they do need to be about interpersonal interaction (for example, asking "how to dress a table" wouldn't be a good fit on IPS). (For those wondering, I'm an active user on IPS).